# Why do I get "Operation not permitted" when trying to mount a volume using sshfs and MacFUSE?

Tags: mac-osx, sshfs

I installed MacFUSE (from http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/downloads/list), restarted, and then downloaded sshfs-static-leopard.gz, and moved sshfs-static-leopard to /usr/sbin/sshfs (and did a chmod 755 on it).

I've configured an Ubuntu machine at work (with the hostname "daryls") so I can ssh into it without a password.  But when I try `sshfs daryls:/ /Volumes/daryls -oauto_cache,reconnect,volname=daryls`, I get:

```
warning: ssh nodelay workaround disabled
mount_fusefs: failed to mount /Volumes/daryls@/dev/fuse0: Operation not permitted
```

What operation is not permitted?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.7?  Could it be that sshfs-static-leopard.gz doesn't work with Snow Leopard?  Or perhaps it only works in 32-bit mode?  How do I find out if I'm booting Mac OS X in 64-bit mode?

**Update:** On Friday I tried this with an Ubuntu 11.04 VM (running in VMware Fusion 3.1.3).  I'm pretty sure I just did a regular `mkdir /Volumes/ubuntu` (without sudo), followed by `sshfs ubuntu:/ /Volumes/ubuntu -oauto_cache,reconnect,volname=ubuntu` and it worked.

But today I'm getting the same `mount_fusefs: failed to mount /Volumes/ubuntu@/dev/fuse0: Operation not permitted` error.

I tried creating the /Volumes/ubuntu directory with sudo, which made no difference.  Then I tried running `sudo sshfs ubuntu:/ /Volumes/ubuntu -oauto_cache,reconnect,volname=ubuntu` and got:

```
warning: ssh nodelay workaround disabled
remote host has disconnected
```

But `ssh ubuntu` works.

I have no idea why it was working and now isn't.  I'll try restarting my MacBook Air, just in case.

**Update #2:** After restarting, I ran:

```
$ cd /Volumes/
$ mkdir ubuntu
$ sshfs ubuntu:/ /Volumes/ubuntu -oauto_cache,reconnect,volname=ubuntu
warning: ssh nodelay workaround disabled
```

It worked.

So I still don't have an answer to my question.  But I may have a workaround.

BTW: It says "No" across from "64-but Kernel and Extensions" under "System Software Overview" in the System Profiler (which I opened following [Handyman5](https://serverfault.com/users/82631/handyman5)'s directions).

**Update #3:** After getting the "Operation not permitted" error, I restarted and got it again.  (In other words, restarting is not a reliable workaround.)

**Update #4:** This was working, and then I made the mistake of restarting my Ubuntu VM without unmounting the sshfs volume.  Now I'm getting the "Operation not permitted" error again.  (Perhaps the /Volumes directory is left in some kind of locked state.)

I read [Handyman5](https://serverfault.com/users/82631/handyman5)'s comment below, and then read http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031017061722471 and the man page for chflags.  I then did:

```
$ ls -lOd /Volumes/
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 root  admin  hidden 170 Jul 15 13:22 /Volumes/
$ ls -lOd /Volumes/ubuntu/
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root  admin  - 68 Jul 15 13:08 /Volumes/ubuntu/
```

(According to the chflags man page, the ls option to see flags is -O, not -o.  This is confirmed in the ls man page.)

As you can see, it's not showing any flags.  (Though I wonder what the '@' and '+' signify.  I read http://lists.apple.com/archives/Macos-x-server/2008/Jan/msg00138.html and played with xattr, but didn't learn anything.)

Out of desperation, I tried `sudo chflags nouchg /Volumes` and `sudo chflags nouchg /Volumes/ubuntu` but still go the "Operation not permitted" error.

**Update #5:** It's been a while since I originally posted this, but IIRC this all came from my problems trying to work around [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org) not working with MacFUSE and SSHFS (when trying to use SSHFS to mount a volume running in an Ubuntu VM). I recently learned bout [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io). I installed it, re-installed [SSHFS](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS), and now MacFusion is working flawlessly.

Comment: Researching the "Operation not permitted" error further led me to Mac OS X's concept of [locked files](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031017061722471). I have no idea if this is actually what's causing the problem, but if the OS is somehow locking the /Volumes/ubuntu directory, that could cause the behavior you're seeing. Use `ls -lo` to show file flags; if the directory is locked, it'll have a `uchg` in the listing.

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to http://apple.stackexchange.com/?  (Especially if my bounty expires without resolution.)

Comment: See Update #4 above in response to Handyman5's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the `ls` note; if I could edit comments I'd fix it. :-) I wonder, can you mount the volume somewhere else than `/Volumes` (say in your home directory, or in /Users/Shared)? That would tell you whether the problem was with `/Volumes` specifically or with the mount. Also, I know sshfs can get finicky if the host disappears out from under it, so unloading the FUSE filesystem driver and/or restarting the computer might help here.

Comment: I was able to successfully mount the volume in a subdirectory of my home directory.  I should have thought of that.  That may be a reasonable workaround.  Put that in an answer (or modify your existing answer) and I'll accept it once I confirm it works repeatedly.

Comment: Restarting the computer doesn't work.  (At least not every time.)  Any idea how to unload the FUSE filesystem driver?

Comment: Mounting the volume into a subdirectory of your home directory is actually the very first suggestion in my answer. ;-) As for the broken `/Volumes/ubuntu`, it's possible that the filesystem is a bit wonky from the broken mount and that repairing it with Disk Utility will help. Failing that, [this answer from SU](http://superuser.com/questions/385/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-a-kext-on-mac-os-x) will help you unload the MacFUSE driver.

Comment: Oops.  I don't know how I missed that very first suggestion in your answer.  Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer (so you get the bounty), and I'll report back later after I try Desk Utility and/or the answers you found on SU.

Comment: s/Desk Utility/Disk Utility/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that your user account is not able to mount volumes into the `/Volumes` directory directly. Have you tried mounting `sshfs` into a directory within your own home directory?

Failing that, you might need to have administrative (`sudo`) permissions to run `sshfs`. Try prefacing that command with `sudo` like so:

```
sudo sshfs daryls:/ /Volumes/daryls -oauto_cache,reconnect,volname=daryls
```

As an aside: to determine [whether your Mac is running in 64-bit mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3770):

> 1. Choose **About This Mac** from the Apple menu.
> 2. Click **More Info**.
> 3. Select **Software** in the Contents pane.
> 4. Look for "64-bit Kernel and Extensions: Yes (or No)" under the **System Software Overview** heading.

Answer (score 1):

One day, I was able to sshfs mount my volumes.  The next, I wasn't.  On the command line (terminal), I tried `sudo -i` and was met with "User is not in the sudoers file".  I rebooted and tried `sudo -i` and was sucessful so I tried the sshfs mount again and it worked.  Basically, a reboot fixed me but I have no other details other than that.  OS: Mac 10.11.6 (El Capitan)